# Object is not callable

Tags: python, class

Why is my object not callable? Does anyone know the problem?
This is my code in main `main.py`:

```
def average_wind(dia):
         wind_list=[]
         area=klass.windpower(dia)
         print(area)
```

And this is my code in my class:

```
class Windpower(object):
    def __init__(self,digit):
        self.digit=digit

    def calc_area(self,dia):
        area=(dia**2*math.pi)/4
        return area
        windpower = Windpower(10)
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? You can't be showing us all of the relevant code -- where's the definition of klass? How does average_wind relate to the Windpower class?

Answer (score 0):

`klass.windpower` is already an object of the Windpower class, so you can't instantiate it again. But I think you meant to call the `calc_area` method?

```
area = klass.windpower.calc_area(dia)
```